# Change Magento header Checkout URL

Tags: magento, url, header, checkout

In the header of Magento the checkout url goes to /checkout/onepage/. How can I change this to /onepagecheckout/?

Comment: refer : http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml and update checkout.xml file

Comment: Is there another way to do it? Like modifying a file?

Comment: Actually thanks, I tried it and it works well. I thought the old page would be still there but it is returning a 404 so I am happy with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use url rewrite in this case.

you can refer this [link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml)